# Given final block not properly padded AES256

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have a key, and the I want to decrypt the data using this key, but Given final block not properly padded error appears.

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    byte[] encryptedBytes_updates = cipher.update(encryptedBytes);
    String decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes_updates));
```

I tried some advices from forums, but no luck.

May be someone can help?

Comment: This can happen for many reasons, including: IV is wrong, key is wrong, data is corrupted.

Comment: I have tested a key string, and is is the same. I send data to server, which uses openssl, and then the server sends the data back. I tried locally to encrypt and decrypt data seems to be working, but it does not work with data from the server. Now I have  Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified which line the exception occurs on. Is it the `cipher.update` line, or the `cipher.doFianl` line?

Comment: If you temporarily decrypt with `NoPadding` then you will be able to look at the last block and see what padding the source is using.  Alternatively, the whole block is garbage and you problem is with the key or possibly IV.  I am suspicious of you comparing key "string"; don't do that, compare key **bytes**.  There are different ways to convert strings to bytes and you need to ensure that both ends use the same conversion.

Answer (score 4):

If the message you're decoding is less than 16 bytes, one of the issues may be that you're using the wrong IV. Specifically, this line is incorrect:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
```

You're creating an `IvParameterSpec` from a byte array of all 0's (because you just created it, but didn't fill it with any data). If you're doing the same thing while encrypting, this is the reason encryption/decryption works locally for you.

What you need to do is create the `IvParameterSpec` using a byte array containing the IV that the server sends you. If the server isn't sending you the IV in a separate field, it may be that the IV has been prepended or appended to the encrypted data you receive (this is a fairly common practice). I would trying pulling off the first block (16 bytes) of the encrypted data and use that as the IV. If that doesn't work, try the last block of encrypted data. Or better yet, ask whoever runs the server or read the manual to determine where to get the IV from.

Also, this looks incorrect as well:

```
byte[] encryptedBytes_updates = cipher.update(encryptedBytes);
String decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes_updates));
```

Why would you take `encryptedBytes_updates` and feed it back in to the cipher? `update` decrypts the data, then you're trying to decrypt it again using `doFinal`. Do this instead:

```
String decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes));
```

Comment: Since the mode is CBC, an incorrect IV only garbles the first block. So the padding error would only occur if the ciphertext were 1 block in size.

Comment: @zindorsky: True, my mistake. Edited to reflect that. Left most of the information though since his IV code is almost certainly incorrect anyway.

Comment: What if the server is not using IV at all?

Comment: If not, then you're using the wrong algorithm mode. CBC always requires an IV to operate, if there's no IV the encryption mode the server is using _might_ be ECB. You really need to talk to whoever runs the server or read the manual. Trying to guess all of this stuff isn't going to work.

Comment: I think that the last part will throw the exception, and is likely the answer. If you decrypt twice, it is very likely (about 255 out of 256 times for different inputs) that the padding algorithm fails.